# .htaccess 404 file per country and per language

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site with changing URL according to selected country and selected language like below :

countries list a,b,c,d,.....

so the site looks like a.site.com/en-a/

when switching the lang to french the site will be a.site.com/fr-a/
when changing the country :
the URL will look like b.site.com/en-b/

and when switching the language while the site is b.site.com/en-b/ to french 
url will be b.site.com/fr-b/

so what I am trying to add is the error.php file in my `.htaccess` rules

```
ErrorDocument 404  /error.php?status_code=404
```

which is not working
any advice here ?

Comment: ErrorDocument can not cause redirect loop, do you have RewriteRules?

Comment: @starkeen I think there is a default rule that does that , let's manipulate the 404 redirect , when I put ErrorDocument 404 http://google.com it works and takes me to google

Comment: What happens when you go to /error.php ? does the request go in infinite loop?

Comment: do u mean if I write in the browser url to go to error.php ? that works fine , so lets say b.site.com/en-b/error.php?status_code=404 works fine and takes me there , because the file exists ,,, the rule I am trying to set is when the file does not exist and its 404 @starkeen